# Code Contracts trying to get build errors instead of warnings

Tags: code-contracts

I'm trying to get VS2010 Ultimate with Code Contracts to generate Errors instead of Warnings.

I have this simple test program:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace MyError
{
  public class Program 
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Program prog = new Program();
         prog.Log(null);
     }

     public void Log(string msg)
     {
         Contract.Requires(msg != null);
     }
  }
}
```

It correctly determines there is a violation of the contract:

```
C:\...\Program.cs(10,13): warning : CodeContracts: requires is false: msg != null
```

In my csproj file there is this property field for Debug:

`TreatWarningsAsErrors`>`true`

Is there something else I have to set in the project settings to turn these into errors?

Comment: What's the reason for trying to enforce this, if I might ask?

Comment: i imagine its to make people write code that doesn't break the contracts.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like at this point Microsoft has elected not to make this possible, but they are considering it for the future:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646880/code-contracts-dont-listen-to-treat-warnings-as-errors-setting

Comment: That link is now dead, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code contracts use a rewriter. they show as warnings because they are only calculated after the build completes.

Well i don't really know how it works, but unless you built code contracts into the compiler i do not see how they could be anything but warnings / messages.